# Kept in Hindsight

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I dared not to admit – I lied,
So found “friends” on this trip.
My propensity to grip (sometimes),
Or shoot out from the hip,

Or generosity with tips,
Should keep heads down.

*What do I have?*

**Hint #1**

> I'll likely leave it behind.

**Hint #2**

> But I'm not an animal.

**Hint #3**

> If you can't see it, you may be ahead of me.

Comment: I think it is clear what to do here. My question is: "Is the answer a single word? If it is, how do we know it is the right word?"

Comment: @Sid, "A puzzle whose answer will be a word or a set of words but not a phrase, sentence or sentences"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you have a:

> **tail** - which may be kept in hindsight.

I dared not to admit – I lied,

> Tail sound like tale, something that may be told instead of admitting the truth. (Also, the last four words' initials give tail.)

So found “friends” on this trip.

> If you got a tail, someone is following you.

My propensity to grip (sometimes), Or shoot out from the hip,

> An animal's appendage from the hip, that if prehensile, can grip.

Or generosity with tips, Should keep heads down.

> Tails showing on coins means heads are down. (Taking this as one clue, else just tails are long tips.)

Hints:

> *#1 I'll likely leave it behind* - you will outrun it.
>  *#2 But I'm not an animal* - not the animal type of tail.
>  *#3 If you can't see it, you may be ahead of me* - the tail is behind you.

Least confident of lines 1 and 5, but seems to fit.

Comment: Wow! Someone got it! You absolutely nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> **Money**

I dared not to admit – I lied

> Instead of admitting to a crime, I lied and used money to dodge the consequences.

So found “friends” on this trip

> In continuation of the previous line, by using the money to hire a willing legal team to help get you off, I could see them as "friends".

My propensity to grip (sometimes)

> Having the natural tendency to save your money.

Or shoot out from the hip

> Or sometimes spending money "from the hip", typically the location of you wallet when it is in your pocket.

Or generosity with tips

> Pretty straightforward.  If you have money, you have the ability to be generous with tips.

Should keep heads down

> Placing the money face down makes it easier to identify the bill or coin.

Hint #1

> When you die, you'll leave the money behind.

Hint #2

> Money isn't an animal.

Title: Kept in Hindsight

> You usually don't fully understand what it's like to have money until that situation has occurred.

Comment: Have you noticed the wordplay tag?

Comment: I actually did not... does this make my guess incorrect?

Comment: I don't know what the answer is, but none of your explanations involve wordplay, so I think it's very likely incorrect.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to pay more attention to the tags next time. New to the site, I appreciate your help.

Comment: +1 because I thought this was one of the answers I thought I'd get.